# Batch rename many files from XML 'File Id' value to 'Short Name' value

Tags: xml, linux, windows, unix, cmd

Basically I want to batch rename all files in multiple directories to their 'shortname' values from their 'file id' value. All info exists in an XML file. Files are currently named by their file id.

```
<File Id="12345678" Language="Falls">
        <ShortName>Large/drops.wav</ShortName>
</File>
<File Id="87654321" Language="Rocks">
        <ShortName>Medium/flake.wav</ShortName>
</File>
<File Id="857483" Language="Trip">
        <ShortName>Truck/Axle.wav</ShortName>
</File>
<File Id="432489839" Language="Okre">
        <ShortName>SoundOut/Frog.wav</ShortName>
</File>
```

I assume the steps would be to tell the script to use values for File Id= to search the directory tree, then have it read the Id's shortname from that file's group (file..../file), then write the name to the file, and continue on.

The script will need to be able to differentiate between shortname's for multiple fileIDs (ex: once it's been told to search for 12345678, found it in the directory tree, and told to find it's shortname, it can't use the short name of 87654321 or any other, of course). There's probably about 1000+ files to process, hence my need for automation.

Is this asking too much? Trying in both Linux and Windows, and can't seem to get very far at all. I'm comfortable with basic renaming using grep and file, but this has me stumped.

Comment: The traditional Unix and Windows tools aren't meant to handle XML files. You might want to use an XSLT script to transform the XML files into something that works better with them.

Answer (score 0):

The files are in the same directory? If true, try

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//File' -v 'concat("mv ", @Id," ",ShortName)' -n f.xml
mv 12345678 Large/drops.wav
mv 87654321 Medium/flake.wav
mv 857483 Truck/Axle.wav
mv 432489839 SoundOut/Frog.wav
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not have "xmlstartlet" available on your system, this is the way to go on this :

```
pairsofData=$( paste <( cat xmlfile.xml | tr -d '\n' |  awk -F'</File>' 'BEGIN{ OFS ="\n" }{ $1=$1 ; print $0 }' | sed  -e 's/\(.*\)\(Id=\)"\([0-9]\+\)"\(.*\)/\3/g' ) <( cat xmlfile.xml | tr -d '\n' |  awk -F'</File>' 'BEGIN{ OFS ="\n" }{ $1=$1 ; print $0 }' | sed  -e 's/\(.*\)\(<ShortName>\)\([a-zA-Z\/.]\+\)\(<\/ShortName>\)\(.*\)/\3/g' ) )
while read line 
do
    echo $( echo $line  | awk '{print $2}' ) "and" $( echo $line | awk '{print $1}' )

done <<< "$pairsofData"
```

Swap xmlfile.xml in the command ( It appears two times ) for whatever the name of the file you have  your data in and test it. You should see an output like this :

```
Large/drops.wav and 12345678
Medium/flake.wav and 87654321
Truck/Axle.wav and 857483
SoundOut/Frog.wav and 432489839
and
```

Now you can swap the "echo" inside the while loop for "mv" command and REMOVE the "and" in between them and rerun the command. Your files will be renamed.

Let me know if it worked for you. :)

Note :  there is an extra line being returned, but it is empty, you can ignore it, it will give "mv" command one single error at the end but nothing else.